# Proper indexing of a table give the queries listed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have the following table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [SourceId] [int] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table has the potential to grow big. The most frequent queries ran on this table are going to be:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = 'some@email.com'
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = 'some@email.com' AND SourceId = some integer
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-30'
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-30' AND SourceId = some integer
```

Currently I have setup the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Users_Email_SourceId ON Users (Email, SourceId)
CREATE INDEX IX_Users_CreatedAt ON Users (CreatedAt)
CREATE INDEX IX_Users_SourceId ON Users (SourceId)
```

Are these indexes sufficient for the type of queries listed above? Should I set ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON to OFF if this is going to be a heavily queried table? I am getting a bit confused as to how to setup indexes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would index them this way:

```
WHERE Email = 'some@email.com'
index: Email
or Email, SourceId

WHERE Email = 'some@email.com' AND SourceId = some integer
index: SourceId, Email
or Email, SourceId

WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-30'
index: CreatedAt
or CreatedAt, SourceId 

WHERE CreatedAt BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-30' AND SourceId = some integer
index: SourceId, CreatedAt 
or CreatedAt, SourceId
```

It is difficult to be completely sure of these, what is the selectivity of `SourceId`.  Depending on that, you could try to cover multiple queries with a single index (the first two could be combined and the last two could be combined).  If `SourceId` is very selective (few rows match each value) I'd like to not combine the indexes and go for max performance by using four indexes.

Also, you don't mention how many INSERTS/UPDATES you expect so it is hard to determine how much the overhead of more/fewer indexes will play out.

Also, your `SELECT *` makes it impossible to recommend covering indexes, etc.

Comment: Thanks KM. Should I turn row and page locks off or is that a bad idea? SourceId will not be very selective. There will be a lot of INSERTS (but not that many UPDATES).

Comment: you worry about locks based on the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE frequency as well as the length of their transactions.  If you are mainly just  `SELECTING` this data often and do not have long slow transactions changing it, I would not worry about those until you start having problems.